# Access DOM inspector from Chrome extension script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, adblock

I'm writing a Chrome plugin for my needs. I'd like to be able to select HTML elements like Adblock Plus do to be able to watch changes on the element and its children. I use `MutationObserver` in my `content.js`.

How can I to make it work the way I want? I'd like to trigger it from the popup menu. I see there's this API: `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow`, probably I can make use of it somehow?

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "PageFontStyle",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Changes font style on page",
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "icons": {
        "128":"icon128.png",
        "48":"icon48.png",
        "16":"icon16.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon16.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Page Font Style"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "content.js"],
            "css": ["content.css"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I've seen at least several existing answers, try searching. In short you can use a js library like the one used by uBlock or replicate the exact overlay of devtools by emitting RDP command via chrome.debugger API.

Comment: Did you find solution?